# nodejs, mongodb-update, async, callback is not consider as a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, express, asynccallback

I have a problem with the code below.  Everything goes fine, until the db.collection.update.

At at console.log(n.6), the callback is not consider as a function anymore. And I don't understand why.

The console display:
**callback(errorCode404)
TypeError: object is not a function**

```
var newData = req.body;
...
async.waterfall([
    function(callback){
        console.log('n3');
        db.getConnection(callback);
    },
    function(db, callback){
        console.log('n4');  
        db.collection('dossiers', callback);
    },
    function(dossiers, callback){
        console.log('n5');
        dossiers.update({'_id': mongodb.ObjectID(id)}, {$set:newData}, callback);
    },
    function(result, callback){
        console.log('n6');
        if(result != 1) {
            console.log('n6.1');
            callback(errorCode404);                         
        } 

        console.log('n6.2');
        callback(null, 'Dossier mise a jour.');

    }
], function(err, result){
    ...
});
```

Can someone clarify me about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that the [`update`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html#update) callback has three parameters: error (if any), the count of records that were modified, and a status object.  `waterfall` handles the error parameter, but the last two are passed as parameters to the subsequent `waterfall` function (n6), with the callback being provided as the *third* parameter, not the second.

So you need to change that part of your code to be something like:

```
...
function(dossiers, callback){
    console.log('n5');
    dossiers.update({'_id': mongodb.ObjectID(id)}, {$set:newData}, callback);
},
function(numModified, status, callback){
    console.log('n6');
    ...
```

Comment: Thanx, indeed.   It's clear to me know. When i did console.log the parameters, i see what you means.